# Getting "destroyed" signal in Qt Script

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-signals, qtscript

How to properly connect to QObject's `destroyed` signal from Qt Script?

When I connect to it like to your average signal, it does not work. I did test that I removed the object and that other QObjects did get the signal, but the script function I connected to it is not invoked.

Below is the sample I'm using for testing. The most important part is the line:

```
_engine.evaluate("obj.destroyed.connect(function() { debug(\"obj destroyed\") })");
```

I'd expect it to invoke that function when `obj` is destroyed. The code below ensures that object is deleted when even loop already started and it also tests that the object did send `destroyed` signal to another QObject. What I want to fix is for the script to invoke the script function with `debug("obj destroyed")` after `destroyed` signal is emitted.

ScriptTester.h:

```
#ifndef SCRIPTTESTER_H
#define SCRIPTTESTER_H

#include <QtScript>
#include <QtCore>

class ScriptTester: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ScriptTester(QObject *parent = 0);

private slots:
    void signalTest();
    void boo();

private:
    QScriptEngine _engine;
};

#endif // SCRIPTTESTER_H
```

ScriptTester.cpp:

```
#include "ScriptTester.h"

static QScriptValue scriptDebug(QScriptContext *context, QScriptEngine *engine) {
    Q_UNUSED(engine);
    if (context->argumentCount() >= 1) {
        QString msg = context->argument(0).toString();
        for (int i = 1; i < context->argumentCount(); ++i) {
            msg = msg.arg(context->argument(i).toString());
        }
        qDebug() << msg;
    }
    return QScriptValue();
}

ScriptTester::ScriptTester(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    QTimer::singleShot(0, Qt::CoarseTimer, this, SLOT(signalTest()));
    _engine.globalObject().setProperty("debug", _engine.newFunction(scriptDebug, 1));
}

void ScriptTester::signalTest() {
    QObject *obj = new QObject(this);
    _engine.globalObject().setProperty("obj", _engine.newQObject(obj));
    _engine.evaluate("obj.destroyed.connect(function() { debug(\"obj destroyed\") })");
    if (_engine.hasUncaughtException()) {
        qDebug() << "Exception:" << _engine.uncaughtException().toString();
    }
    connect(obj, SIGNAL(destroyed()), this, SLOT(boo()));

    QTimer *timer = new QTimer;
    _engine.globalObject().setProperty("timer", _engine.newQObject(timer));
    _engine.evaluate("timer.timeout.connect(function() { debug(\"timer timeout\"); obj.deleteLater(); })");
    if (_engine.hasUncaughtException()) {
        qDebug() << "Exception:" << _engine.uncaughtException().toString();
    }

    timer->setSingleShot(true);
    timer->start(100);
}

void ScriptTester::boo() {
    qDebug() << "was destroyed!";
}
```

Note that I don't want a hack like passing `destroyed` first to C++ code and then manually or by a signal informing script of that. I'm searching for an implementation that's done fully in the script.